# MaterializeCSS: Grids and cards carousel effect

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

Can anyone help me in achieving the following carousel (train carousel) effect using grid and cards in MaterializeCSS. I have tried many solutions, but I'm unable to achieve desired results.

[image]

Here is what I have achieved so far: https://jsfiddle.net/c5mq2ezo/1/  (sorry for the images inside the link)

But the problem is I need to create train carousel effect with any number of grids/cards available. Right now it gives unexpected results in visible slide. If I add 4 or 5 cards, it only displays 3 instead of 4. If I add 7 or 8 cards then it displays 4 cards as it should.

Following is the code:

```
 <body class="grey darken-3">


<section>
  <div class="carousel carousel-slider">
      <a class="carousel-item black-text" href="#one">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/samples/insurance.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h6>Insurance</h6>
          <p>Adjusters have photos of cars damaged in accidents; these images, however, are not helping prevent...</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item black-text" href="#two">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/samples/manufucturing.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h6>Manufucturing defects</h6>
          <p>Production lines are often equipped with cameras, but it can be challenging to infer quality or safety problems...</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item black-text" href="#three">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/samples/retail.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h6>Retail</h6>
          <p>Recommend products that match your customers' style, analyze reviews or survey data for topics and trends</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
      </a>

      <a class="carousel-item black-text" href="#three">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/samples/retail.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h6>Content filtering</h6>
          <p>Adjusters have photos of cars damaged in accidents; these images, however, are not helping prevent future ...</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
      </a>

      <a class="carousel-item black-text" href="#three">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/samples/retail.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <h6>Card 5</h6>
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
          I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
      </div>  
      </a>


  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
    width: 340px !important;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card{ 
    border-radius: 8px; 
    position: relative !important;
    right: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: you can provide us the fiddle or share your code which you tried so we can help you along :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c5mq2ezo/1/

Comment: @Manjunath I have edited the question with more information

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add the cards to the carousel adding the class `carousel-item` to the card and not using the `a` tag:

```
<div class="carousel ">
  <div class="card carousel-item">
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">Card 1</span>      
      Card 1 content
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
</div>
```

[View in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrZkk.png)

The issue is when you add the picture because the pic uses all the space and the content is displayed below the carousel, maybe with some styles it could be fixed, I don't know too much about CSS.

Hope this be helpful.